# TDO unable to capture MSB of Shifted data in JTAG

Tags: digital-logic, jtag

With reference to my previously asked question [What stage is used to shift out TDO in JTAG?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/509739/what-stage-is-used-to-shift-out-tdo-in-jtag)
I have another querry.

The JTAG document says that the last bit of data/instruction should be shifted out the same time as Exit1 State is activated. However it also states that TDO is tri-stated in all the states except Shift-IR and Shift-DR states i.e just when Exit1 state is activated, in the following negetive edge of clock, TDO is tri-stated. That means the last bit information sampled on TDI in Exit1 state is lost! How to deal with this situation? I have simulated the RTl for JTAG and sharing the simulation results (waveform snapshot). Please guide.

[image: Simulation JTAG]

As seen in waveform, thr IDCODE register is shifted out with value 0xc3631093 and last 2 bits i.e 1 and 1 is shifted out on IDCODE_shift_out at 48.50 us and next 49.50 us respectively.

However TDO only captures the first 1 at 49.0 us and the next 1 is not captured as TDO becomes Z. The test sequence is such that I am shifting out IDCODE on TDO through the state Shift DR -- Exit 1 DR -- Update DR -- Run Test Idle and so on.

Just for reference, these are the different states coded

```
parameter TEST_LOGIC_RESET=0,
                RUN_TEST_IDLE=1,
                SELECT_DR=2, 
                SELECT_IR=3, 
                CAPTURE_IR=4,
                SHIFT_IR=5,
                EXIT1_IR=6,
                PAUSE_IR=7,
                EXIT2_IR=8,
                UPDATE_IR=9,
                CAPTURE_DR=10,
                SHIFT_DR=11,
                EXIT1_DR=12,
                PAUSE_DR=13,
                EXIT2_DR=14,
                UPDATE_DR=15;
```

Edit: Also adding the screenshots for IR selection and IDCODE Shift sequence. Please note, there is no Shift for IR, the sequence for IR is Capture-Exit1 IR-Update IR i.e Just write.

[image: Waveform for IR selection - Selects IDCODE instrcution]

[image: Waveform for IDCODE shift]

The first screenshot is for IR selection with timestamps

@12.5 us: Sel_IR is high in TAP controller

@13.5 us: Load_IR is high, IR value 0x001001 is pre-loaded

@14.5 us: Load IR register gets IR value (one cycle delay to capture). Meanwhile, Exit_IR state in TAP Controller.

@15.5 us: Update_IR is high, actual IR register updated(commited) with 0x001001

@16.5 us: Instruction sent to Decoder, decoder outputs 10 resulting in selection of IDCODE register. Sel_DR is high.

@18.5 us: Shift-DR is asserted, and IDCODE data is read into Shift register (Shift_idcode_q).

@19.0 us: Negedge of TCK, TDO gets LSB of shift data

@19.5 us: Data starts right shifting out from Shift register

Coming to waveform 2 screenshot

@49.5 us: MSB of IDCODE is shifted out. State is Exit-1 DR. Shift_DR is de-asserted.

@50.0 us: TDO is again tri-stated.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of the full IR selection and shift sequence ?

Comment: @Nipo I have added the same.

Comment: Thanks. Could you add the selection phase as well ? Just zoom out to have RTI state before and after.

Comment: You mean IR selection or IDCODE selection phase? I have already shared the IR selection phase.

Comment: <https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug380.pdf#page=171> Table 10.4 mentions (points 5,9 and 15) that if instruction is 6 bits, 5 bits are loaded in shift IR state and last bit is loaded in Exit 1 state when TMS = 1.

Comment: Thanks, Ill try that. Can you please edit in answer format so that I can close this. :)

Comment: Now I understood, that it is the next state that is Exit-1 and not the current state that is Exit 1. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I count correctly, your test bench is only spending 31 cycles in shift-dr. This is probably the cause for the missing bit.

On last Shift-* cycle, TMS=1, but current state is still Shift-*. Next state is Exit1-*. Overall, in order to shift N bits, JTAG chain must spend N cycles in Shift-*, among which N-1 cycles with TMS=0 and last one with TMS=1.

Here, you seem to spend N-2 cycles with TMS=0 and 1 with TMS=1.